# Convert from Proto to XSD

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I need to be able to convert from proto to xsd, I know that there is some tools to convert from XSD to PROTO, but I need the oppositive.

Could be in .NET or Java

Thanks

Comment: I could probably do it in two steps if you want - not ideal, but workable... Via c# (protogen) then xsd.exe on the compiled DTO model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specified example of XSD you'd like to receive in the end. Actually, there are multiple ways how Protobuf messages could be represented in XSD.

Some of questions may arise:

- How would you like to store PROTO fields: as attributes or elements (for simple types like `string/bool/int`)?
- Would you like to have fixed order of XML elements or not? (Another words, would you like to use `xs:sequence` or `xs:all` in your `xs:complexType` definitions?)

I had same issue not so far. I solved my task and described it [in blog post](https://codeofclimber.ru/2017/convert-protobuf-message-definitions-to-xsd-schema/).

Solution for my task was:

- use `protogen.exe` to serialize PROTO to XML representation
- then run custom written XSLT to generate XSD schema

Actually, [I wrote XSLT](https://github.com/halex2005/protobuf-to-xsd/blob/master/xsd-attributes.xslt) for `protogen.exe` to generate XSD. Using it, [this PROTO](https://github.com/halex2005/protobuf-to-xsd/blob/master/tests/protobuf-fields.proto) will be converted to [this XSD](https://github.com/halex2005/protobuf-to-xsd/blob/master/tests/ProtobufToXsdTests.FieldsConverting_XsdAttributes_CheckContent.approved.xml).

You can customize this XSLT for your needs. Hope this helps!

Comment: I followed your blog post and it was very helpful.  Unfortunately I am not too familiar with XSLT and need to 1) write the proto fields as elements and 2) use xs:sequence instead of xs:all.  Would you be able to help with that please?

Comment: @hshah, try out this xslt, hope it do what you want: https://github.com/halex2005/protobuf-to-xsd/blob/master/xsd.xslt

Answer (score 0):

I had to use [Proto to JSON](https://github.com/renenglish/pb2json) conversion tool and [JSON to XSD](https://github.com/raz-varren/JAXSD) conversion tool separately to address different issues. Might help in your case..

Comment: Doesn't protomak make .proto from other things?