# XSLT to change some XSD Element Types

Tags: xslt, xsd

I recently following [hal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191799/hal) answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809748/convert-from-proto-to-xsd) question and managed to convert a Protobuf schema into an XSD.

Since all my date/time elements are defined as strings, I'm looking to run some XSLT which will change all elements whose name contain the word "StartDate" or "EndDate" or ends with "Date", and is of type `xs:string`, into `xs:date`.

Example XSD entry:

```
<xs:element name="ActionStartDate" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="ActionEndDateUpdated" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string" />
```

Expected XSD entry:

```
<xs:element name="ActionStartDate" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" type="xs:date" />
<xs:element name="ActionEndDateUpdated" nillable="false" minOccurs="1" type="xs:date" />
```

I have managed to change some parts of the resulting XSD using [hal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191799/hal) XSLT, but I have no idea how to do the above.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would just set up the identity transformation as the base template (e.g. by declaring `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>`, then you can add a template checking the conditions you have named in the match pattern and performing the change to `xs:date` in the template body:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="xs:element[@name[contains(., 'StartDate') or contains(., 'EndDate') or ends-with(., 'Date')]]/@type[. = 'xs:string']">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">xs:date</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So that is how you would run a complete XSD as the input through an XSLT code that checks for the conditions you have named and implements the required change for the type attribute.

In XSLT 1 you have no `xsl:mode` to declare the identity transformation, so you have to spell it out; furthermore `ends-with` is not an XPath 1.0 function so you need to compare based on string-length counted from the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xs:element[@name[contains(., 'StartDate') or contains(., 'EndDate') or substring(., string-length(.) - 3) = 'Date']]/@type[. = 'xs:string']">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">xs:date</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```